# Can we use hazel-cast in ASP.Net application?

Tags: asp.net, hazelcast

We are using MS SQLServer in our ASP.Net application but we want to move away from this and having a plan to upgrade to Hazelcast. Can we do that?
Please help us.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, Hazelcast supports .Net, see [here](https://hazelcast.org/clients/net/)

Comment: What you need to decide is if you wish to immediately or eventually retire the SqlServer. Hazelcast IMDG can load content from an external source, all you'd need is a JDBC connection (Hazelcast servers are Java), then use the .Net Hazelcast client to retrieve the domain object from the Hazelcast servers.